# Limit MySQL to localhost only - xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

i'm hosting some smaller sites/gameservers on a windows server 2008 R2, and now i can see in my connection log that the database is used more than just local hosted stuff, so i want to limit my mysql to localhost only, and i know by doing that i will not be able to use my "Mysql Control Center" but that is why Xammp is here, there have been "PhpMyAdmin" on it from day one. But how do i make the settings so it is only localhost? and my www.mysqlhostsite.com/phpmyadmin.

Things i got:

```
Windows server 2008 R2
Mysql
Phpmyadmin
xampp
```

Comment: turn off tcp connections, allowing local sockets only

Comment: It may only happen to the mysql, and a "how to do it" is what i need.

Comment: Access control in mysql is to username@clienthost. If you only create XXX@localhost accounts, then it can't be used remotely.

Comment: Barmar - I found a way like yours just make the users connect from "%" to "Servers ip", and that works.

Answer (score 6):

You can limit connections from a specific address (e.g. localhost) with the [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) option.  Configure this in your `my.ini` file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = localhost
```

Alternatively, you can force MySQL to use *named pipes* (a local-only method for connecting):

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = localhost
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
```

Of course, restart the MySQL Service after editing my.ini.

Comment: named pipe is the best way in my knowledge.

Comment: Where should this my.ini be located? \xampp\mysql...?